# Error while printing 2D array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, error-handling

I want to print 2D array using pointers but in the `printf` statement it is showing invalid type argument:  (See error in image below:)

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
        int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        int i,j;
        int *p;
        p=&a;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                printf("%d",*(p+i)+j);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

please help me out with this error.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text. [Edit] your question.

Comment: try `printf("%d", *(p+i*3+j));`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code should be posted as code and not as a picture.

Comment: I have edited post to include the text, and an  embedded image that were both shown in the link you originally used.  This is more permanent, and easier for potential answerers to access.  Links are not optimal for posting question content.  They are however very appropriate for pointing to references you might include for clarification of a point etc.

Comment: If you have not already seen it, this _[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)_ is brief but useful.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - If it makes any difference to your vote to close, post has been edited to fit norms.

Comment: @ryyker done, thanks, you can remove your comment

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

This initializer of the pointer `p` is incorrect.

```
int *p;

p = &a;
```

because the pointer and its initializer have different pointer types and there is no implicit conversion between the types.

This expression

```
*( *( p + i ) + j)
```

is also invalid. The expression *( p + i ) yields an object of the type `int` not of a pointer type.

You can use the following approaches

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    int a[N][N] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    int *p = ( int * )a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *( p + i * N + j ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int ( *p )[N] = a; p != a + N; ++p )
    {
        for ( int *q = *p; q != *p + N; ++q )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *q );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer to a pointer but you're assigning it to a pointer. If you fix that, rest should work fine